# Open System.Windows seems to fail on TryFSharp.org

Tags: f#

Recently I've been using TryFSharp.org in an attempt to learn F# in my spare time.
There's loads of really good examples on http://fssnip.net/ which I've been looking at for inspiration.

Lots of the UI examples have code such as:

```
open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms
...
form.Show()
// Run the application (in compiled application)
Application.Run(form)
```

Unfortunately when I load these into TryFSharp.org I get compilation errors on the open System.Drawing.

Is there something I'm missing that would enable these examples to work?
An example FSharp script is here:

http://fssnip.net/p

If you click on the tryfsharp.org button it'll load in the browser but it will show compilation errors.

--- EDIT ---

As pointed out below it's not expected for System.Drawing to be available within the browser.  However I also have issues with the namespaces System.Windows etc.

For instance

open System.Windows

fails with "The namespace 'Windows' is not defined"

Tried in both IE10 and Google Chrome.

--- END EDIT ---

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you're using scripts from a previous iteration of TryFSharp.  See here: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-visualization#extending-tryfsharp

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I was trying to find the older version of TryFSharp to see whether I could get these snippets to run but I don't think it's around anymore unfortunately.

I'm quite new to StackOverflow.  Can I mark your comment above as the accepted answer?

Comment: I added that bit to the end of my answer, so you can just click the check mark next to my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.Drawing allows you to access GDI graphics functionality and System.Windows.Forms enables you to access windows forms functionality.  Neither of these is available in a browser.

If you want to do this you will need to compile it from a standard .net compiler rather than a limited functionality compiler running inside silverlight.

[`System.Windows.Controls` for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

When I entered this into the TryFSharp editor, it didn't recognize the `Windows` namespace for some reason, but when I ran the script, it executed just fine.

[`System.Windows.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)

> The System.Drawing namespace provides access to GDI+ basic graphics
>   functionality.

[GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> GDI can be used in all Windows-based applications.

This means *not* Silverlight.

[`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx)

> The System.Windows.Forms namespace contains classes for creating
>   Windows-based applications that take full advantage of the rich user
>   interface features available in the Microsoft Windows operating
>   system.

Not all functionality available from previous iterations of TryFSharp are currently available.  Look [here](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-visualization#extending-tryfsharp) for the current way of accessing the Cavnas.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

There's definitely other examples I've found that specifically mention running in TryFSharp.
  
For instance there's this link here: http://ecfcae6434894ad79588106d501d2222.cloudapp.net/Tutorials/BuildingRichUI/Section1.html

Unfortunately this fails to compile on open System.Windows.Controls and some of the other namespaces.

Comment: @AndyB I just tried it and System.Windows.Controls loads just fine for me.  That namespace _is_ available for Silverlight.  Forms and Drawing are not.

Comment: It was more the System.Windows.Controls I was interested in. I picked a bad example for my question.
I've tried this in chrome and IE10 but calling open System.Windows is failing with "The namespace 'Windows' is not defined.

Comment: @AndyB That sounds like you're running into something else.  I'm currently running it in OS X in Firefox and I can use `System.Windows` just fine.

Comment: It looks as though I can #r "System.Windows" and then it'll open the Windows.xxx namespaces correctly.  However when loading scripts such as this one: http://fssnip.net/9V it fails on calls to App.Dispatch() with "The field, constructor or member 'Dispatch' is not defined"